# Angularjs hide security information

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if we use facebook login in angularjs application.how to hide the credentials such as **appid**,**secretkey** etc in the below code

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: appId',
    cookie: true,xfbml: true,
    channelUrl: return_url,
    oauth: true
    });
  };
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
  },
  {scope:fbPermissions});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use angularJS and hence javascript, you are not asked in most cases to give your appKey.

Only AppID is accessible by end users.
In most cases App Id can be taken from javascript sources. The only thing that you should be worry about is App Secret.